# Why would $\geq$ not be complete?

Tags: relations, order-theory, complete-spaces

We have the relation in $R^2$ given by
$(( x_1, x_2) R (y_1, y_2)) \iff ((x_1 \geq y_1) \land (x_2 \geq y_2))$ for all $( x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)$ in $R^2$.

The professor said it is not complete by giving a counter example. Say $( x_1, x_2) = (1,2)$ and
$(y_1, y_2) = (2,1)$.

Why would we say it is not complete when we have that for all $x, y,$ either $xRy$ or $yRx$ or both?

It seems to me that $\geq$ gives us the opportunity to say it is complete. Is this not valid when we have pairs like $( x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)$? Can we use any numbers to say this relation is not complete when we already have the conditions $x_1 \geq y_1$ and $x_2 \geq y_2)$ given to us at the beginning?

Comment: Is it true that $(1,2)\ge (2,1)$ or $(2,1)\ge (1,2)$ under your definition?

Comment: You use the same letter $R$ for the underlying set and for the relation. Also, you should make it clear what is to you a complete relation (from the context it seems to be a relation $R$ such that we always have $xRy$ or $yRx$, which is not the case; in order theory there is a different notion of completeness).

Comment: Sure, we can take any random pairs of numbers and then it would not be true. I guess my question is, can we do that even when given the conditions to have this relation? In what case, would a relation similar to this be complete?

Comment: The relation is complete if *for all* $x$ and $y$ at least one of $x\ge y$ or $y\ge x$ holds. We found a pair $x=(1,2)$ and $y=(2,1)$ for which neither holds. So it's not true that at least one holds for all $x$ and $y,$ hence the relation is not complete. When checking a condition that has a "for all" quantifier, it always suffices to provide one counterexample to show that the condition does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but here goes.

This relation is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so for it to be a total order (which seems to be the way you use 'complete' here) we would need that for any $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $x R y$ or $y R x$ (not exclusive or). I think we can agree your professor gave two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can call $\vec{x}=(1,2)$ and $\vec{y}=(2,1)$. Both of these lie in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so for the relation R to be a total order we need $(1,2) R (2,1)$ or $(2,1) R (1,2)$. But since neither of these are true ($1\leq 2$ but $2\not\leq 1$ in both cases), we know that his vectors are incomparable, meaning the relation can't be a total order.